# Fedora. Screen Recording

Tags: fedora

Anyone know how to get Screen Recording software for fedora?

I have been looking for a couple of months, and have tried a few things, but I haven't had success. Obviously free is preferred, but I'm not going to be a nanny over it, I'll take a paid propriety tool if its somewhat reputable.

I tried a program that worked for me when I use to use Ubuntu, but I couldn't get it working on fedora (I can't remember the name, but I will look it up and edit it in after I finish writing this).

#### EDIT: I tried peek...

And it recorded its self, but not the screen. I installed the suggested libraries, and various configurations but nothing.

Another option I considered was:

#### [Screen Rec](https://screenrec.com/)

...however, when I went to their **[downloads page](https://screenrec.com/screen-recorder#download)** it showed support for Linux, but it only gives a source that demonstrates how to download it using the Debian `APT` package manager, which obviously is not going to work for fedora.

If this is a dup, thats fine, I just want to find somthing that works smoothly. Please don't mark this as a dup though, unless you know that the other question offers a fedora specific answer, and not just a general linux answer. Since I started using Fedora, I have found that its hard to locate software, because when a blog/post/thread (or whatever) references Linux, 4 out of 5 times, they are actually references Debian Linux, which is obviously not **All of Linux**.

Comment: Try OBS https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#fedora-installation-unofficial

Comment: @Gantendo works great. And the repo DL for the DNF package manager installed no problem. Software self configured its-self. The software is feature-filled. This is perfect. Nice call Gantendo. If you answer the question with your suggestion I will select it as being the correct answer, otherwise I am going to answer it, because it is a good answer. The software I used to record on Ubuntu, just wouldn't work for me since I moved to fedora, I am really happy to have this, and its free/open sourced!

Comment: OK I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try OBS. It works on Fedora. It is free and opensource.

OBS is a cross-platform screencasting and streaming app. https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#fedora-installation-unofficial

You may want to bookmark https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't think anyone thought it was off topic until you came along